# Possible to attain happiness without support, through art?

Tags: art, life, faith

Is it possible to attain happiness without support, through art, not overt meditation?

I'm not really an *expert* on any art, but take the question (somewhat) seriously.

Comment: maybe i should delete this already. chuffed with an idea =/= much

Answer (score 1):

Working on your hobbies, advancing your career, developing a family, nurturing a child, going on vacations, increasing your wealth, raising your status in the world, attaining fame in society etc. could all make you happy.

Here, I'm guessing that art could be your hobby or career.

But the point is that these types of happiness would not last forever.

The goal of Buddhism is to find the sort of happiness that would be permanent.

On another note, please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/7673/471) on why actors may go to hell and [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/5760/471) which elaborates on the point that music and entertainment is not allowed for those undertaking the training of the [eight precepts](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/atthasila.html), [ten precepts](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/dasasila.html) or ordination into [monkhood](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/sv/bhikkhu-pati-intro.html).

Comment: Very good and precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ruben](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/22164) already told

Of course it is possible to gain happiness trough art but this kind of happiness has underlying suffering, at least because it is constructed and not lasting, is dependend and needs nurishment. The only way to gain freedom of suffering is the noble eigtfold path, and sensuallity is an obstacel to develop it, at least.

How ever, since art is a fine skill, it might be very usefull to have such, since the skill of a craftsman or artist is at it's heat the same like the path to develop the path. Buddha was very skilled in all kinds of arts and that not only gave him a good background in how to develop things, but also a understanding that things are done by deeds. Later he would use his talent to develope something that goes beyound oldage, sickness and death.
All the means to learn that skills have been brought as samples drawn from craft and art.

[The Craft of heart](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/thai/lee/craft_en.pdf), by Ajahn Lee might introduce you to the art of the Noble ones.

(*Note: This answer is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial means or other wordly gains*)